# Scribe-LinkedIn Search API

Tags: java, api, linkedin-api, scribe

I want to fetch data from the LinkedIn API for that I am using the Scribe library.All requests are giving me data as expected but when I tried two facet in the url then scribe is not able to get data from LinkedIn API. 
If I gave this URL : **http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?facets=location,network&facet=location,in:0** then it gives me proper result

but if I entered this URL:
**http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?facets=location,network&facet=location,in:0&facet=network,F** i.e. URL containing multiple facets then it gives me this output:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <error>
     <status>401</status>
     <timestamp>1292487039516</timestamp>
     <error-code>0</error-code>
     <message> [unauthorized].OAU:CiEgwWDkA5BFpNrc0RfGyVuSlOh4tig5kOTZ9q97qcXNrFl7zqk-   Ts7DqRGaKDCV|94f13544-9844-41eb-9d53-8fe36535bbc3|*01|*01:1292487039:VseHXaJXM2gerxJyn6kHhIka7zw=</message>
      </error>
```

Any kind of help to solve this will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw that there is no help available so I decided to fix this bug of Scribe library and I am able to fixed that bug by modifying code.The modified code of Scribe is [here](https://code.google.com/p/scribe-multiple-facets-request/source/checkout).You can see as well as you can take checkout. And if you want to use that code then you need to just create its jar and add it to your projects build path.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for Play Framework to easily integrated with LinkedIn's OAuth: geeks.aretotally.in/projects/play-framework-linkedin-module. Hopefully it can help. You should def check out Play, very very cool Java framework. It's based on Scribe.